# What's the difference between 'Client initiated aborted execution' and 'Exception aborted execution' in SQL query store?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, sql-query-store

When I query my query store with `SELECT * FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats WHERE plan_id = 12400` there are 3 `execution_types` in query store.

```
0 - Regular execution (successfully finished)

3 - Client initiated aborted execution

4 - Exception aborted execution
```

What's the difference between 'Client initiated aborted execution' and 'Exception aborted execution'?

How to avoid them?

Thanks,

Comment: Regarding your "how to avoid them" question, make sure queries are not cancelled or time out (#3), and ensure no errors are raised on the server side (#4).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find hard documentation for those descriptions, but generally they'd mean

- Client initiated aborted execution: The client (application, SSMS query, etc) cancelled the transaction / query
- Exception Aborted execution: An exception / error was raised which caused the query to abort

You'd have to find out why the execution failed to prevent the latter (check error logs) and simply *not* kill the query to prevent the first.

Comment: Thank you Scsimon, I also checked SQL log and there is no error logs...

Comment: Maybe it wasn't logged.